# Click a button when the page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button (#test-element) it makes the page refresh but I want it to then run a function after the page is refreshed to open the cart by clicking a button automatically(.cart-contents). How do I run a function after the page is refreshed if the add to cart button (#test-element) was clicked. So the page refreshes and clicks another button(.cart-contents)?

```
<script>
 $("#test-element").on("click",function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
 location.reload(true);
 }, 500);
 });
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#test-element").on("click",function() {
  setTimeout(function () {  
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cart-contents").trigger('click'); 
  }, 500);
  });});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess instead of "reloading" you could direct the user to the current URL but with some value added to the query string, and in the page's code you could check for that value and execute the intended operation.  This seems like overkill though.  Why are you reloading the page in the first place?

Comment: @David so essentially, I need the page refreshed after the add to cart button is clicked so it updates a few things within the cart.

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense.  If the action of "adding to the cart" is an AJAX operation then the response should contain whatever data you need, or the code should fetch the updated data in another AJAX operation.  If the action of "adding to the cart" is a form post then the resulting redirect should put the user back on the page with the updated data.  While my above suggestion should work if you try it, this all still sounds like very much the wrong design.

Comment: @David the only thing that does not update is the little notification saying there is an item in the cart. I can possibly not go down this route to refresh the whole page if there is a way to refresh just a modal to update the data, if you know how to do that?

Comment: How to fetch the data you need and what page elements you need to update would be entirely up to you, nobody here knows anything about your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (only applied to the current session page) to keep your clicking state. After the page is reloaded, we can remove that temporary storage.

You can try [this sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/m2bwf19v/) for the test

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-element").on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      sessionStorage.setItem('isReloaded', 'true');
      location.reload(true);
    }, 500);
  });
  $(".cart-contents").on("click", function() {
    alert('cart-content triggered')
  })
  const isReloaded = sessionStorage.getItem('isReloaded');
  if (isReloaded) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('isReloaded')
    $(".cart-contents").trigger('click');
  }
});
```

This way is not perfect but it can solve your basic needs in terms of keeping page states.

Answer (score 1):

You *probably* don't need (or even want) to actually do this.  It sounds like an over-complicated solution to a problem of mixing AJAX and page loads/requests, and the *real* solution would be to fix whatever design problem is causing you to want to do this to compensate for it.

Having said that...

Each time the page loads, the JavaScript starts anew.  So any information you want to persist between page loads needs to exist outside of the page code itself.  One such place to persist data could be `localStorage`.

So your operation to reload the page would write a value to `localStorage`:

```
$("#test-element").on("click",function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("clickCartContents", true);
    location.reload(true);
  }, 500);
});
```

And when loading the page you can check to see if that value was set:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("clickCartContents")) {
    $(".cart-contents").trigger('click');
    localStorage.removeItem("clickCartContents");
  }
});
```

Comment: is there no way to refresh div/modal data if a button is clicked?

Comment: @Asn: Define "refresh div/modal data".  Nobody here knows anything about your application, we only know the code you've shown us in the question.  And there is no single universal operation to "refresh data".  If there is some data you need from the server, you can use AJAX to fetch that data.  If you need to update elements on the page, you can update them in your JavaScript code.

Comment: The data I want is showing but sometimes I will have to refresh the page for it to display fully and some parts do be missing

Comment: @Asn: I'm afraid that still tells me/us *nothing* about the problem.  If you're asking whether there's a way to get information from the server without reloading the page then, yes, the technology you're looking for is called "AJAX".  If you're asking whether there's a way for JavaScript to update the page content then, yes, JavaScript can manipulate DOM objects.  If you're looking for a single line of code you can copy/paste which will magically "make your page work without refreshing" then, no, nobody here has that.

Comment: okay no problem, it may just be a bug, the data no displaying correctly, because it displays correctly on one page but not the other, anyways thanks for your help!